# Can we use Bootstrap to design Apache FreeMarker email template in Spring MVC project?

Tags: spring-mvc, twitter-bootstrap-3, html-email, freemarker

I want to design my email template in Spring MVC project and I am using Apache FreeMarker template to send the email content.

**newUserRegRequest.ftl** (Email template file in resource folder)

```
<html><head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>
</head>
<body>
    <h2>Hi,</h2>
    <h3>New Registration for BidManager Development</h3>
    <div>
        First Name : ${bmUserModel.firstName}
        Last Name  : ${bmUserModel.lastName}
        Country    : ${bmUserModel.country}
    </div>
    <pre><a class="btn btn-default" href="https://stackoverflow.com/">Accept</a>   <a class="btn btn-default" href="https://stackoverflow.com/">Reject</a></pre>
</body></html>
```

I have used Bootstrap button classes but don't know where I should keep its CSS library (it's an Eclipse Dynamic web project). The below is how I have configured the email server.

**spring-servlet.xml**

```
<!-- Start: Email Configuration -->
<beans:bean id="bmRegMailSender" class="org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl">
    <beans:property name="host" value="${bm.smtp.hostName}"></beans:property>
    <beans:property name="port" value="${bm.smtp.port}"></beans:property>
    <beans:property name="username" value="${bm.smtp.username}"></beans:property>
    <beans:property name="password" value="${bm.smtp.password}"></beans:property>
    <beans:property name="defaultEncoding" value="${bm.defaultEncoding}"></beans:property>
    <beans:property name="javaMailProperties">
        <beans:props>
            <beans:prop key="mail.transport.protocol">${bm.transport.protocolName}</beans:prop>
            <beans:prop key="mail.smtp.auth">${bm.smtp.authorization}</beans:prop>
            <beans:prop key="mail.smtp.starttls.enable">${bm.smtp.tls}</beans:prop>
            <beans:prop key="mail.debug">${bm.mail.debug}</beans:prop>
            <!-- <beans:prop key="mail.smtp.ssl.enable">${bm.smtp.ssl}</beans:prop> -->
        </beans:props>
    </beans:property>
</beans:bean>
<beans:bean id="bmFreeMarkerConfig" class="org.springframework.ui.freemarker.FreeMarkerConfigurationFactoryBean">
    <beans:property name="templateLoaderPath" value="classpath:/templates/"></beans:property>
</beans:bean>
<!-- End: Email Configuration -->
```

When I send the email, this is how It looks like in my Yahoo mail:

[image]

I want to show like below:

[image]

The answer would be acceptable if there is some alternate way to design FreeMarker template (Except inline styling). Please ignore the button text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Email is a similar looking, but different beast than html5. There is some email clients that support some html5 and some css3.

- https://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/

It depends on how much you want your email to look good on different clients. Most of the popular email clients will use a `<style>` block in the header. You already declared you do not wish to use inline styles, which means your email will not look very good in Outlook. Good looking buttons without inline styles  are going to be a huge challenge as you have noticed with Yahoo mail.

I appreciate your enthusiasm, but I don't think you have a full grasp on the aggravating complexities of email development.

Good luck.

Comment: Thanks!!! @Gwally, I appreciate your ans. Plus one for the link you provided but it doesn't ans my ques.

Comment: I don't use Freemarker templates, so I can't help you. Zurb Foundation for Email has a good system for email templates. I would look for a Zurb 1.0.5 email template and compare it to your Freemarker and see if you can come up with a template that does most of what you need. http://foundation.zurb.com/emails/docs/v1.0.5/index.html. Zurb 2 requires SASS and other fun, while the 1.0.5 template is self-contained.